# Unexpected Feature Names in scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the TfidfVectorizer from scikit-learn to convert a list of words into a TF-IDF matrix. However, I'm encountering some unexpected behavior where the feature names generated by the vectorizer don't match the words in my input text.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import brown
import re

txt = brown.words()
txt_str = " ".join(txt)

def custom_tokenizer(text):
    tokens = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
    return tokens

documents = [txt_str]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer)
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

print(feature_names)
```

I've noticed that some feature names in the output are neither present in my txt nor in the tokens generated by the custom_tokenizer. Additionally, some feature names seem to be numeric values or arbitrary characters and words.

I've tried various approaches, including using a custom tokenizer to ensure accurate tokenization, updating scikit-learn. It works on smaller texts as well as when the max_features is set to low enough value. However, for my project I do need all the features so I am trying to figure out what is going on.

Why I'm getting these unexpected feature names and how I can ensure that the feature names correspond accurately to the words in my input text?

some of the features are zwei' 'zworykin'.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question to include examples of these unexpected tokens.

Comment: I can confirm that I get `zwei` as a feature name out.  That _does_ appear as a substring in `txt_str`, at position 2516713, inside of the name(?) `Bluthenzweig`.  I get `zweig` as a token when I run `custom_tokenizer` on the entire string, but _not_ when I run it on a small segment surrounding the name, so I really don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you some examples of unexpected feature names ?

From my side, I don't think there is any problem extracting features.
The words not present in feature names, are words with special characters like -  ' or $. WHen you extract the text with the function custom_tokenizer, you get two tokens for example polyether-type, gives "polyether" and "type" tokens

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import brown
import re

txt = brown.words()
txt_str = " ".join(txt)

def custom_tokenizer(text):
    tokens = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
    return tokens

documents = [txt_str]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer)
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()

print(f"Nb features                     : { len(feature_names)}")
print(f"Nb words in brown               : { len(txt) }")

# nb uniq lowercase words in brown
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(txt))
mylist = [ x.lower() for x in mylist]
print(f"Nb uniq lowercase words in brown: {len(mylist)}")

# in li1 and not in li2
def Diff(li1, li2):
    set_dif = set(li1).difference(set(li2))
    temp3 = list(set_dif)
    return temp3
li3 = Diff(mylist,feature_names)

def info(text):
    custom_tokenizer(text)
    try:
        s=list(feature_names).index(text)
        print(f"The text {text} was found in features at position : {s}")
    except:
        print(f"The text {text} was not found in features")    
    

print(f"10 first words not in feature_names : \n { li3[0:10]} ")

info("season")
info("mosquito")
```

Nb features                     : 42432

Nb words in brown               : 1161192

Nb uniq lowercase words in brown: 56057

10 first words not in feature_names :
["season's", 'non-farm', "chip-o's",
'polyether-type', 'take-off', '1-0', 'spring-back', '$50',
'mosquito-plagued', 'anti-submarine']

The text season was found in features at position : 33478

The text mosquito was found in features at position : 24918

Comment: 'zwei' 'zworykin' are some of them, my feature length is also different it is 42396